# Accelerating a looped animation over time

Tags: animation, drivers, nla-editor, actions, looping

I've got a looping animation set up for a ground plane so it looks like there's motion (kind of like a repeating conveyor belt), but I'd like to make it accelerate linearly over time.
Here's a preview of what I kind of mean.
[Webm Preview](https://webm.red/dr2f.webm)
What should be happening is the loop should be getting progressively faster and faster as time goes on. Though in the example it's just separate clips scaled to different values, which makes it looked stepped.

I figured this was something I could accomplish with curves, but now I'm not so sure.

I had also tried repeating the clip in the NLA editor, then using a driver to influence the action's length scale. This works to a degree, but the final value isn't actually the same as it should be.

So for example, I had an action repeat using the "repeat" option and have a driver scale the length of it from 1.0 to 0.25. The final speed of the animation wouldn't actually be the same speed as if I had manually taken one instance of the action and scaled it to 0.25. It's actually much faster. Probably because it's scaling over the length of the entire repeated clip, rather than on each clip individually. Which is wrong in terms of what I'm after.

Hopefully what I've wrote isn't too confusing. I've done some searching here for some answers, but nothing really was all that helpful to my situation, so a proper answer would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Turns out the extra speed is caused by the animation playing at the same time the clips are shrinking.
This results in an increased speed than expected because it's adding the speed of the playback to the shrinking clips. Kind of like scrubbing.

I ended up fixing it by finding a value that would match the final speed, while looking correct as it plays. In this case, having the driver scale the clips by 0.5 matched the final speed of 0.25 perfectly. If there's another proper way to do it though I'd be happy to hear it.